# Use custom key serializer only for keys which actually are of the type overridden

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have the following field (map of maps):

```
private final Map<Class<? extends Something>, Map<String, ? super Something>> somethings;
```

I need to serialize the `Class<?>` keys using `Class::getSimpleName` instead of `Class::toString`, hence I have created my custom key serializer:

```
public final class ClassSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Class<?>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Class<?> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeFieldName(value.getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

... and I'm using it on the field with `keyUsing`:

```
@JsonSerialize(keyUsing = ClassSerializer.class)
@JsonProperty("somethings")
private final Map<Class<? extends Something>, Map<String, ? super Something>> somethings;
```

The problem is that this key serializer is used also when serializing the internal maps which contain a simple `String` as key, so causing a `JsonMappingException` with message `class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Class`.

I understand what happens but I don't know how to tell Jackson to use such serializer only for the keys of type `Class`, and not for all the keys that it may potentially find inside.

Any idea?

Comment: seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836372/json-custom-key-serialization-of-nested-maps. The solution there is quite obvious, maybe you are looking for something "cleaner"

Comment: @dariosicily that's what I did but I was looking for something cleaner

Comment: @Pedro that's what I did but I was looking for something cleaner

Comment: I think the second option in the accepted answer of that question is as clean as it gets. I was looking at Jackson's source and there seems to be no way around it.

Comment: It may be worth opening an issue for it on Jackson's Github. Maybe request adding a keyUsingNested boolean to the JsonSerializer annotation.

Comment: If `Class` keys are just in the main map and not inside you could do `ClassSerializer extends JsonSerializer` and check  `value instanceof Class` inside the method.

Comment: @dariosicily yes I did that, I was just looking for a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I ran out of ideas, if some viewer had one I would like to know it too.