# Map of Instant to list of objects - jackson serialization/deserialization

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson

I have a spring boot app and the following `DTO` class:

```
public class CarDto {
    private Map<Instant, List<CarModelDto>> dateToCarModels = new HashMap<>();

    // getters/setters omitted for brevity
}
```

When I make a call from `postman` it looks like this:

```
{
    "dateToCarModels": {
        "1544612555": [{
            <obj1>
        },
        {
            <obj2>
        }],
        "1544785355": [{
            <obj1>
        }]
    }
}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize Map key of type
`java.time.Instant` from String "1544612555": Failed to deserialize
java.time.Instant: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text
'1544612555' could not be parsed at index 0; nested exception is
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: (...)
```

That is understandable as I have `Instant` as a key map (and pass `String` in json - since JSON keys must be strings). 

Is there any better way to fix it than [writting own key serializer/deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272043/jackson-modules-for-map-serialization) ?